# How to read a file line by line and store a specific value

Tags: java, file, class, netbeans

I need some help i've been stuck on for a while now since i'm new to java. I have made a login panel in the console where there is a default username and password set to login with. and they can create an account which stores the username in a username.txt file and the password in a passwords.txt file. I want to know how i can get it so the functions reads the txt files for the username and password line by line until it matches the username with an existing one in the username file and same with the password so it logs in.

This is the read from file function:

```
public static void readFromFile() throws Exception {
    BufferedReader saveUsrFile, savePwFile;
    try {
        saveUsrFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("username.txt"));
        String line_u = saveUsrFile.readLine();

        while (line_u != null && saveUsrFile.readLine().equals(LP.username)) {
              cusUsr = saveUsrFile.readLine();
        }
        saveUsrFile.close();

        savePwFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("passwords.txt"));
        String line_p = savePwFile.readLine();

        while (line_p != null && savePwFile.readLine().equals(LP.password)) {
              cusPass = savePwFile.readLine();
        }
        savePwFile.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the login panel:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoginPanel {

    static String username;
    static String password;

    public LoginPanel() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean flag = true;    
        Passenger p = new Passenger();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(flag == true) {
            System.out.println("Enter Username: ");
            username = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
            password = input.nextLine();

            if ((password.equals(p.DefPass) && username.equals(p.DefUser)) || (password.equals(p.cusPass) && username.equals(p.cusUsr))) {
                System.out.println("Passenger login successful!");
                p.display();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please check your username or password and try again!");  
            }   
        }
    }   
}
```

Someone please help me and tell me how i can get it to read the file line by line until it has a match and allows the user to login.

Comment: you check the previous reading for non null and then read again within the head of the while loop. Doesn't seem to be what you want. Read before the loop, then check for non null in the loop header and read again in the loop as last statement may what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified flow would be like

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String username, password;
        System.out.print("Enter Username: ");
        username = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Password: ");
        password = input.nextLine();

        if (authenticated(username, password)) {
            System.out.println("Passenger login successful!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please check your username or password and try again!");
        }
    }

    static boolean authenticated(String username, String password) {
        BufferedReader saveUsrFile, savePwFile;
        boolean usrFound = false, pwFound = false;
        try {
            saveUsrFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("username.txt"));
            String line_u = saveUsrFile.readLine();
            while (line_u != null) {
                if (line_u.equals(username)) {
                    usrFound = true;
                    break;
                }
                line_u = saveUsrFile.readLine();
            }
            saveUsrFile.close();

            savePwFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("password.txt"));
            String line_p = savePwFile.readLine();
            while (line_p != null) {
                if (line_p.equals(password)) {
                    pwFound = true;
                    break;
                }
                line_p = savePwFile.readLine();
            }
            savePwFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return usrFound && pwFound;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter Username: hello
Enter Password: bye
Please check your username or password and try again!
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter Username: hello
Enter Password: Abc123
Passenger login successful!
```

**Content of username.txt:**

```
hello
world
abc
xyz
hi
bye
```

**Content of password.txt:**

```
Abc123
456Abc
Xyz123
456Xyz
123Abc
123Xyz
```

**Note:** In this demo, `username` and `password` are not checked for their order in the respective files.

Comment: Thank you very much! you are a life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Java NIO. You have nice method which returns stream of lines from file, which is cool because you can do all this fancy stream stuff like this:

```
String password = "givenPassword";
Path path = Paths.get("passwordFileName");
Optional<String> passwordOptional = Files.lines(path)
      .filter(line -> password.equals(line))
      .findAny();
boolean isPasswordFound = passwordOptional.isPresent();
```